# An example of a smooth map between manifolds that is a topological embedding, but is NOT a smooth embedding.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have been reading Lee's book on smooth manifolds and have come across the problem,

> An example of a smooth map between manifolds that is a topological embedding, but is NOT a smooth embedding.

I am having some problem conjuring up an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Okay, I have come up with an example. Namely taking the map $\pi : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $\pi(x) = x^3$. This has continuous inverse $\sqrt[3]{x}$ but this is not smooth since it does not have a derivative at $0$.

If you find another (non similar) example I would like to hear it though!

Answer (score 4):

If the definition of smooth embedding requires a smooth local inverse, then map the real line to itself by $x\mapsto x^3$.

Here's a fancier example, where the image isn't even a smooth submanifold of the codomain: Map the real line into the plane by sending each positive number $x$ to $(\exp(-1/x^2),0)$, sending each negative $x$ to $(0,\exp(-1/x^2))$, and sending $0$ to $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

A primitive example: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $x\mapsto (x^3,0)$. $f$ is smooth and a topological embedding, but is not an immersion, so it is not a smooth embedding. Replacing the third power by the third square root, you get a topological embedding that is not differentiable.

(Note: I could just as well have chosen $\mathbb{R}$ as the target instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since of course diffeomorphisms are just special embeddings).